# How to make a custom keyboard?

Tags: ios4, user-interface, keyboard, uitextfield, uitextview

What are the rules I need to follow, when creating a custom keyboard for a UITextView?

1. Is it OK to use a subclass of UIView?
2. Do I need to implement a specific protocol?
3. Should it contain a variable with a specific type and name?
4. Anything else?

At this point I have already made my own keyboard with the buttons; and it shows up when the UITextView object becomes the FirstResponder as expected. But I cannot use it and I would like to know if there is a "proper way" or if I just have to find my own way to make things work.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Set inputView property of UITextView with your custom keyboard & refer to this link:

[UITextView inputView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3539520/uitextview-inputview)

Comment: Thanks. I had actually found the link you mention before, but I was hoping for a better way. Some mehod by which I could have the same as with the standard keyboard, except for what I don't want. I finally did not find this "ideal solution" and also had to build my "own way".