# Custom keyboard backspace button

Tags: ios, unicode, keyboard

I've created a custom keyboard with my own Unicode characters... The app works great but when I press the back space it will sometimes not backspace and other times it will.. and often after I've gotten it to delete the previous character with my backspace the other letters buttons will no longer type the unicode characters I want...

Here is one of my Unicode characters code:

```
textViewString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@%@", textView.text, char6String];
    [textView setText:textViewString];
```

Where "char6string" would just be one of my unicode characters in this case "π"

Here is the backspace buttons code:

```
if ([textView.text length]>0) {
        textView.text = [textView.text substringToIndex:([textView.text length]-1)];
    }
```

Comment: How have you created the custom keyboard? because it sounds like an issue with the keyboard and way you have implemented it rather than the code you have presented.

Comment: As of now they are just buttons, nothing more.. and when you press those buttons it runs the code I provided,

Comment: Ok, hmmm, is this code running in the background or on the main thread. Background threads trying to manipulate UI's will do all sorts of unpredictable things.

Comment: Nope, that's the whole app haha!

Comment: Not sure if this will help, but I found this post of using a custom keyboard http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3539520/uitextview-inputview

Comment: It had to do with glitches involving the new Unicode characters that came out a few months ago... Apple hasn't adapted fully to them yet, answered a workaround below, thanks for the help though +1

Comment: Ugg, very nasty! I hate having to do things like that. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I figured out the problem and it's a messy solution.. for whatever reason when you trio to add any of the new unicode characters that came out about 4 months ago to a text field via code it adds that unicode character along with a weird glitches unicode character that doesn't exist resulting in uncopyable text and 2 characters added... so now I need to detect if when a button was pressed to add a character if it changes the length by 1 or 2 and if it changes the length by 2 it's a new unicode character and I need to do an auto-delete then and there, otherwise if it only increases by one it's fine and I don't need to do anything!

My new add character to textView string looks like this for each button:

```
length1 = [textView.text length];
textView.text = [textView.text stringByAppendingString:char1String];
length2 = [textView.text length];
if (((length2)-(2))==length1) {
    [textView setText:[textView.text substringToIndex:length2-1]];   
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm doing something similar in one of my apps and haven't seen any issues by using `setText:` rather than `textView.text =`.

```
NSUInteger length = [self.textField.text length];
if (length>0) {
    [self.textField setText:[text substringToIndex:length-1]];   
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm still getting the issue /: hmmm it's an interesting problem, I have no clue what could be causing it because the code seems to be fine!